# How can I create creative soft light?

Tags: flash, lighting, wedding

I've been doing photography for a year and I've become curious about soft light and its use in Wedding photography. What are some methods to create soft light?

Comment: As written, this question is very broad. I can easily imagine a book on soft light for wedding photography. Generally, this works best if you can make your question more specific — describe a real-world problem and ask for solutions, or at least focus on a manageable aspect of the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean for light to be soft or hard?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12829/what-does-it-mean-for-light-to-be-soft-or-hard)

Comment: @mattdm, maybe a dupe, but the previous question is more about the *difference between* soft/hard (theory), while i think this is intended to be about *how* to produce soft light (more practical/creative methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reflector, an external flash, a softbox on a flash...These are the main less heavy solutions, that can be used.

There are a lot of videos and tutorials you can read and watch for any particular way!

Hope that helps!

Comment: that helps....im learning...and will share with you the knowledge when its almost done . :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you mean! Could you make it clearer to me?

Comment: @GigabyteSahel If you are looking for more comprehensive answers than this, I recommend waiting a bit longer to mark one as accepted. If you are happy with this, I suggest editing your question to be more focused on these basics.

Answer (score 1):

You soften light by diffusing it.  Anything that increases the surface area that light is coming from will work.  It can be a softbox, an umbrella, a reflector or even bouncing the flash off a ceiling.

The softness or hardness of a light comes from how directional the light is and the size of the area the light is coming from largely determines how directional the light is.

Beyond that basic primer, using soft light is a complex and deep part of the field that can't be summarized in one question and answer.

Comment: Yeah, if this is all we are going to say, might as well close the question as a duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12829/what-does-it-mean-for-light-to-be-soft-or-hard

Comment: Matt, I think you are right! The post you are talking about answers the question very well.

Comment: well nice ive got it ..good thing is u've shared the previous question and that is much enrich with examples ..good

Comment: @mattdm - yeah, I personally hadn't seen that question before, but I think it would be a good candidate for a duplicate.  I suppose we could possibly additionally go in to more detail about each type of softlight (umbrella vs softbox vs bounce vs reflector) but this is really broad to pick a particular direction to go in.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best source of soft light is natural light through a window, doorway, etc.  As AJ points out, it's about finding a large source of light.  It's usually suggested that you use a north-facing window if you're in the northern hemisphere, since you'll get diffuse light as opposed to direct sunlight through the window.